# Pause src so I can calculate a var

Tags: javascript, html, src

I have a set of code that reaches out via a src and takes a defined array and displays a calculated set of values via the src. My problem is I need to run some commands to reach out and grab a global var and run some computations with that global var before I send it to the array that jumps out with the src. So I just was wondering if there was a way to "pause" the src so I can grab that global var.

```
<script>
 var hi = "3919 e douglas loop"
 function init() {
    window.onmessage = (event) => {
    hi = event.data;
 }
}
   var rprAvmWidgetOptions = {
  Token: "742980EF-52EE-46F2-AEFB",
  Query: hi,
  CoBrandCode: "btso48",
  ShowRprLinks: false
}
</script>
<script src = "//www.narrpr.com/widgets/avm-widget/widget.ashx/script" > 
</script>
<body onload="init();" style="background-color:transpartnt;">
```

Comment: Hello, might be useful to show some code so we understand better what you're trying to do. Just Providing an explanation isn't enough. Thanks.

Comment: @rottenoats ok, there is the code. and as a preface yes I know this code is missing a lot of semi colins but its running in a Wix HTML box

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***debugger*** keyword into your javascript source code to pause the javascript execution whenever you need

example:

```
var a='Hello'
debugger;
var c=a+'done';
```